# Innertopmargin space for mdframed break page

Tags: mdframed

I have using `mdframed` and expecting to set the `innertopmargin space` for the continued next page, but in my `\mdfsetup`, `innertopmargin=20pt` only work for my first dashed box rather than the break page dashed box.

[image]

Here is my .tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfsetup{tikzsetting={fill=white, draw=red, line width=0.5pt,dashed,dash pattern= on 3pt off 3pt},linecolor=none,everyline=true, innertopmargin=20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=10pt,skipbelow=10pt]
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```